# Is Control.Monad.Reader.withReader actually Data.Functor.Contravariant.contramap?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm working trough the book [Haskell in depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/161729540X) and I noticed following code example:

```
withReader :: (r' -> r) -> Reader r a -> Reader r' a
```

This looks like `contramap`. What the relationship between `Control.Monad.Reader` and `Data.Functor.Contravariant`?

Comment: `Contravariant` captures contravariant functors on the category Hask. `ReaderT` is a contravariant functor from Hask to a slightly more complicated category than Hask.

Comment: Futrher down the rabbit hole I go. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Reader`'s type parameters aren't in the right order for that to be `contramap` for it. A `Contravariant` functor always needs to be contravariant in its last type parameter, but `Reader` is contravariant in its first type parameter. But you can do this:

```
newtype FlippedReader a r = FlippedReader (Reader r a)

instance Contravariant (FlippedReader a) where
    contramap f (FlippedReader x) = FlippedReader (withReader f x)
```

`Reader` is also almost a `Profunctor`, with `lmap = withReader` and `rmap = fmap`, but that doesn't quite work since `Reader r a` is really a type synonym for `ReaderT r Identity a` (although you could use another `newtype` wrapper to make it work like I did above). And `(->)` actually is a `Profunctor` with equivalent behavior, and it's isomorphic to `Reader`.

Comment: `newtype FRT m e a = FRT (ReaderT e m a)`. This is a `Profunctor` whenever `m` is a `Functor`, and I believe an `Arrow` whenever `m` is a `Monad`.

Comment: @dfeuer Yup -- `newtype FRT m e a = FRT (ReaderT e m a) deriving (Category, Arrow) via Kleisli m`

Comment: @duplode, yeah, I knew it was a `Category` but I wasn't totally sure about `Arrow`. I don't think I ever realized that `ReaderT` is a flipped version of `Kleisli`, though it's pretty obvious.

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed; I don't think I'd have realised it either hadn't I stumbled upon [this (Scala!) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61899370/2751851) a while ago.