# Why is the bind operator (>>=) defined as it is?

Tags: haskell, bind, monads

I have been studying Haskell for several weeks now (just for fun) and just watched Brian Beckman's great [video introducing monads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhuHCtR3xq8).  He motivates monads with the need to create a more general composition operator.  Following this line of thought, if I have two functions:

```
f :: a -> b
g :: b -> c
```

the composition operator should satisfy

```
h = g . f :: a -> c
```

and from this I can infer the correct type of the `.` operator:

```
(.) : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

When it comes to monads, suppose I have two functions:

```
f :: a -> m b
g :: b -> m c
```

It seems to me that the natural choice would have been to define a generalized composition operator that works as follows:

```
h = f >>= g :: a -> m c
```

in which case the `>>=` operator would have a type signature of:

```
(>>=) :: (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)
```

But actually the operator seems to be defined so that

```
h a = (f a) >>= g :: m c
```

and thus

```
(>>=) : m b -> (b -> m c) -> m c
```

Could someone explain the reasoning behind this choice of definition for bind?  I assume there is some simple connection between the two choices where one can be expressed in terms of the other, but I'm not seeing it at the moment.

Comment: Your operator exists [and is called `(>=>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-). As you suspect, it can be defined in terms of `(>>=)`, and vice versa. `(>>=)` is used more often than `(>=>)` because, in practice, it tends to be more convenient in most circumstances. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23051842/), as well as the first part of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61904261/), for related discussion (albeit looking at the matter the other way around).

Comment: Briefly put, it's simlar to composition vs application. Both are useful, but application is usually more common in programming.

Comment: Awesome... It makes sense that the application syntax should be more convenient most of the time.

Comment: I would say that your proposal (known as "kleisli composition" `(<=<)`) is actually more fundamental than `(>>=)`, mathematically speaking, and `(>>=)` is mostly a programmer-biased convenience.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> Could someone explain the reasoning behind this choice of definition for bind?

Sure, and it's almost exactly the same reasoning you have. It's just... we wanted a more general *application* operator, not a more general composition operator. If you've done much (any) point-free programming, you'll immediately recognize why: point-free programs are hard to write, and incredibly hard to read, compared to pointful ones. For example:

```
h x y = f (g x y)
```

With function application, this is completely straightforward. What's the version that only uses function composition look like?

```
h = (f .) . g
```

If you don't have to stop and stare for a minute or two the first time you see this, you might actually be a computer.

So, for whatever reason: our brains are wired to work a bit better with names and function application out of the box. So here's what the rest of your argument looks like, but with application in place of composition. If I have a function and an argument:

```
f :: a -> b
x :: a
```

the application operator should satisfy

```
h = x & f :: b
```

and from this I can infer the correct type of the `&` operator:

```
(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

When it comes to monads, suppose my function and argument are monadic:

```
f :: a -> m b
x :: m a
```

The natural choice is to define a generalized application operator that works as follows:

```
h = x >>= f :: m b
```

in which case the `>>=` operator would have a type signature of:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Comment: Thank you for making clear this distinction in purpose of the two operators.

"If you don't have to stop and stare for a minute or two the first time you see this, you might actually be a computer."  I was also quite relieved to note that I am still human (in spite of studying Haskell)   :)

Comment: I don’t really buy the essentialist argument “our brains are wired to work a bit better with names and function application out of the box”, since studies of beginner programmers often find significant difficulty with variables, function application, and value-level programming generally, since natural languages tend to be more function-level, continuous, and event-oriented. I *do* buy that our brains are wired *by the languages we use* to prefer this style for reasons of familiarity.

Comment: Uh, an i the only one that cannot see how the types of the point vs point-free line up? In the first f is applied to a value (the result of g x y; so assuming g::a->b->c, f must be c->d). In the second, f is applied to a value which happens to be the function ., right? So the two f’s cant have the same type, unless g x y has the same type as (.). That seems misleading to me (if ive understood it at all). Or is this a consequence of (f .) not meaning f applied to .? [in sml there is a difference between (f o) and (f (op o)); if the same distinction applies here, what does (f .) mean?]

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `f (.)` is `f` applied to `(.)`; `(f .)` is shorthand for `\h -> f . h` (to a first approximation), that is, `(f .)` is `(.)` applied to `f`. This is called a section. There is also a flipped section: `(. f)` means `\h -> h . f`. This syntax is specific to infix operators. Instead of `h = (f .) . g`, I could have written `h = (.) ((.) f) g` to make the way it parses as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 28):

You can search for your operator [on Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E++%28a+-%3E+m+b%29+-%3E+%28b+-%3E+m+c%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+c%29&scope=set%3Astackage), and see that it is called `(>=>)`. Its definition in terms of `(>>=)` is [quite simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#%3E%3D%3E):

```
f >=> g = \x -> f x >>= g
```

In some sense `(>=>)` is better reflective of the idea to generalize composition, but I think `(>>=)` works better as a primitive operator simply because it's practical in more cases, and easier to relate to do-notation.

Comment: This makes sense, and thank you for giving the explicit connection between the two operators.

Comment: This should probably be a separate question, but was `>>=` defined with `do` notation in mind?

Answer (score 22):

`(>>=)` is *not* a composition operator. It's an application operator.

```
(&)   ::              a -> (a ->   b) ->   b
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

There's also `(=<<)` (from `Control.Monad`), which corresponds to the more usual application operator `($)`:

```
($)   ::            (a ->   b) ->   a ->   b
(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

For composition, we have both `(<=<)` and `(>=>)` (again from `Control.Monad`, the first being exactly analogous to `(.)`:

```
(.)   ::            (b ->   c) -> (a ->   b) -> a ->   c
(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
```

(`(>=>)` is just `(<=<)` with its arguments flipped; `(>=>) = flip (<=<)`)

---

While we are comparing types, you might want to look at how `fmap` fits in.

```
($)   ::              (a ->   b) ->   a ->   b
fmap  :: Functor f => (a ->   b) -> f a -> f b
(=<<) :: Monad m   => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

`($)` and `fmap` take the same type of function, but apply it to different types of argument.

`fmap` and `(=<<)` take different types of functions, but apply them both to the same type of argument (though in different ways).

Comment: This is a very helpful summary.  Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why the argument order of `>>=` resembles continuation passing style instead of function application?

Comment: a side note for a casual reader, see also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545818/is-monad-bind-operator-closer-to-function-composition-chaining-or-functi/34561605#34561605) earlier [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234632/monads-with-join-instead-of-bind/11249714#11249714) (disclaimer, written by me) with some more verbiage and even an illustration.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that thinking in terms of `( >=> ) :: ( a -> m b ) -> ( b -> m c ) -> ( a -> m c)` often feels more natural as it is closer to usual function composition and in fact it *is* composition in the Kleisli category. Many of Haskell's monad instances are actually easier to understand when looking at them from this point of view.

One reason why Haskell chose `( >>= ) :: m a -> ( a -> m b) -> m b` might be that this definition is in a way the most universal one. Both `>=>` and `join :: m ( m x ) -> m x` can be reduced to `>>=`:

```
( >=> ) f g x = f x >>= g

join mmx = mmx >>= id
```

If you add `return :: x -> m x` to the mix it also possible to derive `fmap :: ( a -> b ) -> m a -> m b` (Functor) and `( <*> ) :: m ( a -> b ) -> m a -> m b` (Applicative):

```
fmap f ma = ma >>= ( return . f )

( <*> ) mab ma =
    mab >>= \f ->
    ma  >>= \a ->
    return ( f a )
```

Comment: Re. my remark that Monad instances are easier to understand in the Kleisli Category: e.g. the state monad just becomes `(X x S) -> (X x S)` for any 'state' `S`. See https://youtu.be/vZ9cS0NOMKs?list=PLhgq-BqyZ7i7MTGhUROZy3BOICnVixETS&t=2124

Comment: It's satisfying to see all these other functions defined in terms of a single basic more fundamental one.  Following your suggestion I guess if I see a Monad that is confusing I should try rewriting it with >=> to see if that sheds any light on in.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason. `(>>=)` can also be derived from `(>=>)`: `m >>= f = (const m >=> f) ()`. So neither is "more universal".

Comment: You're right @DanielWagner. I wasn't aware of this definition of `>=>`.

Comment: ... and `>>=` can be famously reduced to `join` and `fmap`: `m >>= k  =  join (fmap k m)`.